# duplicate identifying algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Rather than having two for loops : first from (var = i) 1 to length-1 of the input array and the second from i to length (using var k) then compare each array[i] == array[k], return true if an identical pair is found false if not found.

Only an array is used as the single parameter for this algo.

Can this still be optimized?

Comment: If you are trying to do a search, you could try a binary search which would operate on a (merge-sorted) sorted array. Probably, this would be an optimized way of searching.

Comment: And that'd be Θ(n lg n)? Is my current algo Θ(n^2)?

Comment: In some of your comments it gets misleading. Do you want to *find matches in two different arrays*,  or *find duplicate values in one single array* ?

Comment: duplicate values in an array

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to tackle this depending on the memory restrictions.

With constant memory, you can sort the 2 arrays O(nlogn), and step the arrays together, advancing the pointers if the number is smaller. This will be O(n). This sums up for a total of O(nlogn).

If you can use O(n) memory, you can create a Hash Set from the first array (O(n)), and traverse the second and break if the set contains the number from the second array. This will be N*O(1) which is O(n).